# How to configure maven-compiler-plugin to java 17

Tags: java, maven, java-17

Hello I'm upgrading my project from JDK 1.8 to JDK 17.
In `pom.xml` I have the following configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I want to make this configuration work with JDK 17, so I tried to change the source and target to '17' but I had the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project routing-service: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
```

I can't find this configuration setting for JDK 17, do you have any ideas?

**Edit:**
The full stack trace of this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile
(default-compile) on project routing-service: Fatal error compiling:
error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
execute goal
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile
(default-compile) on project routing-service: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:306)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by:
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Fatal error compiling
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by:
org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.CompilerException: error: release version 17 not supported
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess
(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:198)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
error: release version 17 not supported
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.reportDiag (Arguments.java:891)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.handleReleaseOptions (Arguments.java:311)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.processArgs (Arguments.java:350)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Arguments.init (Arguments.java:246)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:185)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:119)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask (JavacTool.java:68)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess
(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:135)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:1140)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:301)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Comment: I would try two things. (1) Try upgrading to version `3.11.0` of the plugin, which appears to be the latest version as of this comment. (2) Check that the JDK being used is at least version 17.

Comment: Often one needs to increase the `version`. Often the IDE supports Ctrl-Space into the start of the version text.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of the [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) looks like this:

```
<project>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.11.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

</project>
```

I would also suggest to use the most recent version of the maven-compiler-plugin as shown here.
Also it is required to install an appropriate JDK17+ which looks like that because of the error output:

```
Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported
```

Comment: After your advices it is still the same, I editet my question - I adde the full error.
Actually, I don;t know what '17' is  wrong, I deleted the source and the target

Comment: The error output: `release version 17 not supported` means you are using a JDK less than 17... just check via `mvn --version` and post that output...

Comment: that is the output : 

Apache Maven 3.9.4 (dfbb324ad4a7c8fb0bf182e6d91b0ae20e3d2dd9)
Maven home: C:\Oprogramowanie\apache-maven-3.9.4-bin\apache-maven-3.9.4
Java version: 17.0.7, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
Default locale: pl_PL, platform encoding: Cp1250
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: Compiling on plain command line ? Or using Jenkins or from within an IDE? Have you set JAVA_HOME? Have you configured a bin directory of a Java installation via PATH ?

Comment: now it's ok, I realized that in plain command line I had Java 17, but in the IntelliJ in project Java 11, so I reseted the IntelliJ.. Thank you

Comment: @khmarbaise your comment helped a lot and i was able to solve my issue

Comment: Why did this solution get upvotes?!  It didn't work.  At least you set us on the right path, but still.  Solutions should be tested before they're posted

Thanks for all your contributions to this site; the world thanks you as well

Answer (score 0):

Run the command below (Check maven version). It will show you the version of Java maven is using.
I had the same error with a lower version of maven until i installed maven 3.9.6 for JDK 17.

> "mvn --version"

Output ==
Apache Maven 3.9.6 (bc0240f3c744dd6b6ec2920b3cd08dcc295161ae)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven
Java version: 17.0.10, vendor: Red Hat, Inc.,